# Let Alexa ask the user a follow up question (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

**Background**

I have an Intent that fetches some Data from an API. This data contains an array and I am iterating over the first 10 entries of said array and read the results back to the user. However the Array is almost always bigger than 10 entries. I am using Lambda for my backend and NodeJS as my language.

Note that I am just starting out on Alexa and this is my first skill.

**What I want to archive is the following**

When the user triggers the intent and the first 10 entries have been read to the user Alexa should ask "Do you want to hear the next 10 entries?" or something similar. The user should be able to reply with either yes or no. Then it should read the next entries aka. access the array again.

I am struggling with the Alexa implementation of this dialog.

What I have tried so far: I've stumbled across this post [here](https://gist.github.com/habuma/675a4efb4a657391a4b0159e9fda78f5), however I couldn't get it to work and I didn't find any other examples.

Any help or further pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial gets the concept right, but glosses over a few things.

1: Add the yes and no intents to your model. They're "built in" intents, but you have to add them to the model (**and rebuild it**).

2: Add your new intent handlers to the list in the `.addRequestHandlers(...)` function call near the bottom of the base skill template. This is often forgotten and is not mentioned in the tutorial.

3: Use `const sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();` to get your stored session attributes object and assign it to a variable. Make changes to that object's properties, then save it with `handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(sessionAttributes);`

You can add any valid property name and the values can be a string, number, boolean, or object literal.

So assume your launch handler greets the customer and immediately reads the first 10 items, then asks if they'd like to hear 10 more. You might store `sessionAttributes.num_heard = 10`.

Both the YesIntent and LaunchIntent handlers should simply pass a num_heard value to a function that retrieves the next 10 items and feeds it back as a string for Alexa to speak.

You just increment `sessionAttributes.num_heard` by 10 each time that yes intent runs **and then save it** with `handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(sessionAttributes)`.

Comment: Thank you! With your explanation and the tutorial I managed to make it work!

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is something called "Paging".
Let's imagine that you have a stock of data. each page contains 10 entries.
page 1: 1-10, page 2: 11-20, page 3: 21-30 and so on.
When you fetching your data from DB you can set your limitations, In SQL it's implemented with LIMIT ,. But how you get those values based on the page index?
Well, a simple calculation can help you:

```js
let page = 1 //Your identifier or page index. Managed by your client frontend.
let chunk = 10
let _start = page * chunk - (chunk - 1)
let _end = start + (chunk - 1)
```

Hope this helped you :)

Comment: I am struggeling with the Alexa Dialouge implementation, not with accessing the data. I have added a line in the post to make it more clearer. Thank you for your efforts nontheless!

Comment: @YannickBorschneck You said that you can a whole data from Alexa and picking the first 10 entries. The same way you can pick the 11-20 entries, you don't really need special Alexa implementation.